# Eclipse error on deploying AppEngine project

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using the Eclipse with the Google AppEngine plugins (Java) and following the http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading.html tutorial.

Everything works fine locally, but when I try to deploy to AppEngine I get an error

```
"Error While signing in"

An error occurred while trying to sign in 400 bad request. See the error logs for more details.
```

This error is before I enter any login info or anything.

I am copy/pasting the App ID from the AppEngine website so Im pretty sure I got it right.

I have no idea where the logs are on this thing, so any help there would also be appreciated.

Comment: Is it reproducible every time? I'd have same issue few times, but only few

Comment: Yes every time, I also imported one of the Demo projects same thing.

Comment: Same here, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 7):

Try logging out and back in again.  That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change your proxy settings!
Please go to Window -> Preferences
Then from General find Network Connections and update your proxy settings.

This must solve your issue.